# Error in Calling a WebService From Android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to call the web service CelsiusToFahrenheit at http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx in my Android App. I am using ksoap2 and I am setting the parameters as follow:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
```

And calling the service as follows:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("CelsiusToFahrenheit", 32);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
MarshalDouble marshaldDouble = new MarshalDouble();
marshaldDouble.register(envelope);
envelope.dotNet=true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // Throws Error

Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
String[] results = (String[])  result;
```

But line androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); throws an error saying Unable to resolve host "www.w3schools.com": No address associated with hostname.

Any help will be appreciates. My guess is I did not set up SOAPAction, URL, or Method_NAME, Namespace correctly. Here is http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL if you need to take a look.

Final Edit: I was able to resolve this issue by following the instructions in the link in the following [Android - What should I use to get data from remote db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780558/android-what-should-i-use-to-get-data-from-remote-db)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your SOAP_ACTION link and it appears that it is invalid.

"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" returns "404 - The page cannot be found"

What you need to do is change that.

Your POST should look more like this:

```
POST /webservices/tempconvert.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3schools.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
      <Celsius>string</Celsius>
    </CelsiusToFahrenheit>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Well, this is the link that works http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx  How do I set up my parameters knowing this link.

Comment: @Dogahe Try replacing SOAPAction to `/webservices/tempconvert.asmx`

Comment: No, I changed to what you suggested and still the same error.

Comment: Well I don't know quite as much about SOAP, but my REST POST was successful. Here's how I did it: URL=`http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit`; body=`Celsius=25`

Perhaps you can try `/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit` ?

Comment: I understand how to call a webservice and I have done it successfully in iOS but now I am trying to do it from Android and most searches led me to use ksoap2. I think my major problem is how to set up that soap request. Apparently how I have set it up is not correct.

Comment: Can you try just a regular HTTP Post? Also, in the error, does it say `Unable to resolve host "www.w3schools.com": No address associated with hostname.` or `Unable to resolve host "www.w3schools.com/webservice/....": No address associated with hostname.` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61434/discussion-between-dogahe-and-erad).